# Registration in Germany with an English marriage certificate

Tags: germany, family, marriage, translations

My wife joined me last week here in Germany with a family reunion visa. We have an appointment at the district office (Bezirksamt) this week so she can register. The marriage certificates we have are in English and another one in French.

Question: Will they ask for a German translation? Does it have to be legalized/certified?

Comment: What are your citizenships?  The Gemeinde wasn't particularly interested in our relationship when we (British Citizens) registered.  If you are EU and she is not, then they might well be more interested.

Comment: We are both non-EUs

Comment: You can post your update as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did not ask for a German translation and everything went good.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, German authorities will only accept foreign documents if they have an Apostille (basically an extra document vouching for the validity of the original document in a standardized manner) and a translation by a certified translator (of *both* the Apostille, that will likely be in the same language as the original document because it's from the same source *and* the original document).

There may be exceptions if the documents are from the EU, but I guess if you are not EU citizens, your documents will likely not be from a non-EU country.

However, if you already got your family reunion visa, you should *have* all those documents already, because the *Ausländeramt* already required them. If *they* didn't ask for those papers... I guess there might be some exception for you I don't know about.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes; the English version was sufficient for the visa.

Comment: hm, I guess you can just find out. Worst case is you go home empty handed and have to bring the missing papers next time.